# Numerical analysis of wave equation in polar coordinates:

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Is there a simple solution to deal with the problem of radial symmetry when solving a pde numerically. If so can someone provide some references/resources that explain this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to have a spatially smooth solution is for $\partial u/\partial r$ go to zero as $r$ goes to zero.  This means you can use L'Hopitals's rule in evaluating that second term:

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \rightarrow \frac{\partial_r(\partial u/\partial r)}{\partial_r(r)} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2}$

Comment: Is there any other method to deal with this.

Comment: I think I could come up with something.  It would help to know exactly why this method does not suit your purposes.

Comment: Just imagine what your wave form would look like if it didn't go to zero.  You would have a "mountain peak" or "crater" at the origin with an infinitely sharp point.  The curvature there would be infinite.  No physical wave is going to look like that.  However, if you want to treat this as a pure math problem and allow for the possibility of such a wave, even in that case, it can be shown that the RHS of your equation reduces to $4 \Delta u/\Delta r^2$ as long as $u$ itself remains finite at $r=0$.  You can prove it by integrating the equation in a small volume around $r=0$.

Comment: Thanks this is a huge help for me!!!

Comment: @Aspire Glad to be of help!